# /src/bundle.js not found in react with webpack application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Below is my server.js file:

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import middleware from './src/middleware';

const app = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
const config = require('./webpack.config.dev');
const compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
        assets: false,
        colors: true,
        version: false,
        hash: false,
        timings: false,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: false
    }
}));
//app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')));
} else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')));
}

app.get('*', middleware);

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', (err) => {
if(err) {
    console.error(err);
} else {
    console.info(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'));
    console.info('Listening at '+port);
}
});
```

My webpack.config.dev.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: './src/middleware.js',
output: {
path       : path.resolve('./src'), // always use absolute paths
filename   : 'bundle.js',
publicPath : '/assets/'
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
        }
    })
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'css-loader',
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            query: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            query: {
                presets: [ 'react-hmre' ]
            }
        },
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is my middleware:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';

export default (req, res) => {
match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if(error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    } else if(redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if(renderProps) {
        res.status(200).send(`
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Req Management</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.css">
            </head>
            <body>
            <script src='/src/bundle.js'></script>
            <div id='app'>${renderToString(
                <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
                <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
            )}</div>
            </body>
            </html>
            `);
        } else {
            console.log("inside else");
            res.status(404).send('Not found');
        }
    });
};
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "universal-boilerplate",
"version": "1.4.0",
"description": "Universal/isomorphic boilerplate with react, redux, webpack and express",
"main": "src/index.js",
"scripts": {
"lint": "eslint ./src",
"start": "npm run build && cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-node ./server.js",
"build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.dev.js",
"serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node ./server.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "",
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
"babel-core": "^6.22.1",
"babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"cross-env": "^2.0.0",
"eslint": "^3.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"react": "^15.2.1",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^2.6.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux": "^3.5.2",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"webpack": "^1.13.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
},
"repository": {
"type": "",
"url": ""
},
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.13.1",
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
"babel-core": "^6.10.4",
"babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
"cross-env": "^2.0.0",
"eslint": "^3.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"fixed-data-table": "^0.6.3",
"querystring": "^0.2.0",
"react": "^15.2.1",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1",
"react-dropdown": "^1.2.0",
"react-input-autosize": "^1.1.0",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^2.6.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
"react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
"redux": "^3.5.2",
"redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^1.14.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
}
}
```

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux"
import logger from "redux-logger"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger());

const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} store={store}>
        { routes }
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('app')
);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' && module.hot) {
module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
    store.replaceReducer(require('./reducers').default);
});
}
```

I was trying to deploy this code to Heroku. Did some changes in webpack.config.dev.js file. Not able to revert back. Before the code was working fine locally. Now not working locally also.

[Folder structure is shown below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqGsy.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the directory structure and food that are used in above code ?

Comment: I have attached the folder structure image. Didnt get what you meant by food. can you please elaborate??

Comment: I have trimmed ASAP begging from your questions before, and as an editor I expect question contributors to read and understand edit messages sent to their notifications widget. Since this question contains urgent begging, I am downvoting. Please do not add [questions indicating urgency, impatience or entitlement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and remember that most people here are **volunteers**. Thank you!

Comment: @abhishek sorry that was a typo. It is  files not food

Comment: @halfer.. I apologise for that.. thanks for reminding.. will make sure that it won't happen again... thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')));
```

This makes `src/` the root of your static resources; in other words, `/SOME.FILE` is looked up as `src/SOME.FILE`. Extending this to your url, `/src/bundle.js`, it will be looked up as `src/src/bundle.js`, which obviously is incorrect.

There are a few solutions:

- use `/bundle.js` instead of `/src/bundle.js` in the HTML
- prefix the path for the static middleware with `/src`:

  ```
  app.use('/src', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')));
  ```

I think the latter would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why your code isn't working locally. it may be because you have a typo. You are checking for:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'develospment') {
```

Presumably you meant 'development'...

Comment: Resolved the typo. Still getting 404 for bundle.js. Please help.